# Cannot delete B2C Azure Tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am unable to delete the b2c tenant created by me during a lab demonstration of how to integrate social IDP to a web app. I followed and completed all the processes but the delete tenant button stays greyed out.....It says "Remove Domain Services"...and has been stuck on there ever since[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpM1N.jpg)... Click on the Hyperlink to view image

[remove domain services error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpM1N.jpg)

But once i click there to remove it...It displays nothing....
[After clicking on "Remove Domain services"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwD7R.jpg)

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at this [similar issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/55433)..?

Answer (score 0):

According to the link provided by @Raghavendra- MSFT Identity.We can create an user account named like `'admin@personal_b2c_account.onmicrosoft.com'` in B2C directory, and assign the `'global administrator'` role. Logging in as this user, there will be no error to remove domain services, only to remove users. Removing the personal account from the B2C directory, and we are able to delete the directory after that.

And click `Azure AD Domain Services` in the picture shown, the `welcome to azure!` interface will also appear.It seems to be a bug in the system. Because the domain services error will only come if you ever had enabled Azure AD domain services on your environment.
[image]

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer