# Azure prevent Tenant deletion requiring to Remove Domain Services that don't exist

Tags: azure, active-directory

I am trying to delete an Azure Active Directory Tenant, but delete button is disabled and I am required to remove Domain Service. The issue is that I do not have any domain services.
[image]

When I click on the link to remove domain service, it takes me to welcome page

[image]

Any idea how can I get this fixed and possibly delete the tenant?

Comment: Did you try to delete AzureAD domain services using this link?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/delete-aadds#delete-the-managed-domain

Comment: This is useless as it takes you to the same place - It doesn't exist so you just see the graphic above. Anyone found a way around this?

Comment: I have the same issue and mine is a B2C Tenant - not sure if that's relevant. I've deleted it from the Host AD it sits in (weird) but that made no difference

Answer (score 0):

This is linked to this: [Cannot delete B2C Azure Tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64426417/cannot-delete-b2c-azure-tenant)

The fix is probably the same. You get this error when the account that you are trying to delete with belongs to an external tenant - not the one you are deleting. You can work around this by creating a new user directly on the tenant you want to delete as a Global Administrator then logging in using that account.

Now (after deleting your former account link from the tenant) you can delete the unwanted Tenant.